# iphone opengl createFramebuffer problem

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

now i'm working on opengl to show a view.
My intension is to update opengl view in real-time, if i change the vertices data, the view also changed. But no luck that there is a bug in Xcode.
It is known as createFramebuffer NG for backingWidth/backingHeight is 0 when layout opengl view in the 2nd time.

1.I also tried put createFramebuffer in drawview, also NG.
2.when glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES, i also tried to creat framebuffer again, but also NG.

Other guy also found this:[OpenGL-ES, iPhone and intermittent error: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_OES (0x8CD6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093434/opengl-es-iphone-and-intermittent-error-gl-framebuffer-incomplete-attachment-oe)

Anybody else encounter this problem? How did you deal with it?
Thank you in advance!

```
- (BOOL)createFramebuffer {
    NSLog(@"createFramebuffer");
    //******************************************************
    //Create the framebuffer and renderbuffer object
    //******************************************************
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
    //*******************************************************************
    //Bind the framebuffer and renderbuffer object to the pipeline
    //*******************************************************************
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    //******************************************************
    //Allocate storage
    //******************************************************
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    //******************************************************
    //Attach renderbuffer object to framebuffer object
    //******************************************************
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    NSLog(@" backing size = (%d, %d)", backingWidth, backingHeight);

    if (USE_DEPTH_BUFFER) {
        glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
        glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
    }

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what does NG mean?

Comment: I got a work-around way, but cost more memory, init the opengl view again when the vertices data was changed.
Anybody else has good approach?

Comment: I didn't completely understand (language wise) what you tried to tell us. But as far as I'm guessing I think you somehow assume that just changing some vertices data directly influences what's visible. Just to make this clear: After changing vertex data you must issue drawing calls to actually draw them somewhere. OpenGL is not a scene graph, and it has not crystal orbs built in. All it gives you is some kind of sophisticated pencil and paper.

Comment: Hi,Christian Rau,"NG" means that after i chnage the vertices data and call drawview function, the opengl veiew doesn't change.

Comment: Hi, Datenwolf, sorry for my poor english. your guess is same as what i want. after i change the vertices data and then call drawview function, the opengl veiew should change also, but in fact, opengl view doesn't change at all, it is a known bug for XCODE opengl 1.1. You can see that now Apple's OpenGL template is different from before.

Answer (score 0):

I got a work-around way, but cost more memory, init the opengl view again when the vertices data was changed.
Anybody else has good approach?

Comment: http://www.blog.namar0x0309.com/2011/10/adaptive-resolution/ I recreate framebuffers on the fly.